# Cannot work out vertically expandable UITableViewCells to show buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have my UITableViewCells working fine. I want to be able to click the menu button to expand the height of the cell to reveal a set of buttons as per the image:

[image]

I have code as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == Globals.selectedRowIndex {
        return 335
    } else {
        return 125
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == Globals.selectedRowIndex {
        Globals.selectedRowIndex = -1
    } else {
        Globals.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The buttons all get squished together on the smaller size though. I thought they would just be cropped out of the view. I think I can get around this by having them *hide* on click. I haven't tried this yet.

I also cannot set a height for them as my constraints seem to not be available for anything inside the cell. I don't know why. I can set autoresizing but not constraints.

I think though there's probably a completely better way to do this which I'm missing. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try this library: https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan Checking this out. Forgot I could have looked for a library 

Comment: I've answered this question multiple times and for that made an example project on github, check it out: https://github.com/bavarskis/ExpandingTableViewCell.git

Answer (score 0):

First iterate upto tableCount and assign false. For Example,

```
for i=0;i<tablecount;i++
{
    self.isSelected.append(false)
}
```

For Example, If you have 5 cells means,You will be having Values like this:

```
isSelected = [false, false, false, false, false]
```

Then, While Expanding Cells Assign True.Otherwise assign False

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedIndex[indexPath.row] = indexPath.row;
        if isSelected[indexPath.row]
        {
            isSelected[indexPath.row] = false
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        }
        else
        {
            isSelected[indexPath.row] = true
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        }   
} 
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{ 
                if isSelected[indexPath.row]
                {
                    return 275.0
                }
                else
                {
                    return 110.0
                }

}
```